# Alexa Skill Won't Play My Streaming Audio

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, alexa-skills-kit

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for 2 days, and will post the resolution in the hopes it helps someone in the past. I created an Alexa skill to stream a radio station, and just couldn't get it to play, even using the sample code. Finally I just hardcoded the values sent down the wire, and it *still* didn't work. Here's what I was sending:

```html
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "shouldEndSession": 1,
    "response": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "text": "Playing Somgwriters island",
        "type": "PlainText"
      },
      "directives": [
        {
          "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
          "audioItem": {
            "stream": {
              "url": "http://la2-ssd.myautodj.com:8198/stream.mp3",
              "token": "",
              "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
            }
          },
          "type": "AudioPlayer.Play"
        }
      ],
      "reprompt": {},
      "card": {}
    }
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "statusCode": "200"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the cause in their [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference):

audioItem.stream.url: 
Identifies the location of audio content at a remote **HTTPS** location.
The audio file must be hosted at an Internet-accessible HTTPS endpoint. HTTPS is required, and the domain hosting the files must present a valid, trusted SSL certificate. Self-signed certificates cannot be used. Many content hosting services provide this. For example, you could host your files at a service such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) (an Amazon Web Services offering).